# Check that python tzinfo is UTC

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I'm trying to write up a general way to verify that a given `tzinfo` represents UTC.

So far, the best solution I've come up with is the following:

```
def check_tzinfo_is_utc(tz_info: Optional[Type[tzinfo]]) -> bool:
    is_tzinfo_utc = False
    try:
        is_tzinfo_utc = tz_info.utcoffset(datetime.utcnow()) == timedelta(0)
    except AttributeError:
        logger.warning(f"tzinfo is not a tzinfo object: {tz_info}")
    return is_tzinfo_utc
```

where the idea is to try to use the provided `tzinfo` to get the utc offset of an arbitrary native datetime object.

If the `tzinfo` is not correct, the `except` statement should capture it, and the function return `False`.

I wrote this function with a limited number of use cases in mind, do you see some potential improvements and edge cases where this function would fail?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

comparing the tzinfo object against a set of objects that you consider "UTC" might be a more robust option, e.g.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
import pytz
import dateutil

# what to consider UTC
is_utc = (
    timezone(timedelta(0)),
    timezone.utc,
    pytz.utc,
    ZoneInfo("UTC"),
    dateutil.tz.UTC, # <- this one is not hashable, so use a tuple, not a set
)


def dt_has_utclike_tz(dt, is_utc):
    if dt.tzinfo is None:
        return False
    return dt.tzinfo in is_utc


for z in (
    None,
    ZoneInfo("Europe/London"),
    pytz.utc,
    timezone(timedelta(hours=-5)),
    dateutil.tz.UTC,
):
    print(z, dt_has_utclike_tz(datetime(2022, 1, 1, tzinfo=z), is_utc))
    print(
        "UTC offset zero?", datetime(2022, 1, 1, tzinfo=z).utcoffset() == timedelta(0)
    )

# None False
# UTC offset zero? False
# Europe/London False
# UTC offset zero? True # <- note this one ...
# UTC True
# UTC offset zero? True
# UTC-05:00 False
# UTC offset zero? False
# tzutc() True
# UTC offset zero? True
```